# How can I prove if it's a metric on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

I am studying Analysis by my own and I have a problem in the following question.

Suppose $X=\mathbb{R}$ and define the function $d: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0, +\infty)$ as follows:

$$d(x,y) = \max{\{|x|,|y|\}}$$

Is $d$ a metric on the real numbers?

Provide reasoning for it being a metric, and if not, give a counterexample.

I know that metric on a set X is a function that defines the distance between each pair of elements of X. It needs to satisfy three properties like Non-negativity, Symmetry and Triangle inequality but I don't have any ideas how I can actually prove it!

Answer (score 5):

Since $d(1,1)=1$ and $1\ne0$, $d$ is not a metric.

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is to check that $d$ satisfies (*or not*) the following properties :

1. Symmetry : $\forall a, b , \quad d(a, b) = d(b, a)$
   Obviously, $d$ satisfies this.
2. Separation : $\forall a, b, \quad a\neq b \leftrightarrow d(a,b) \neq 0$
   I leave it to you to check that this fails eg take $a = b = 1$.
3. Triangular inequality : $\forall a, b, c, \quad d(a, c) \leqslant d(a,b) + d(b, c)$