# Prove that $(x,y)\mapsto\max \{ \vert x \vert, \vert y \vert \}$ is a metric on $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm having trouble finding proof for triangle inequality on this problem and i would greatly appreciate any kind of help.
proof that function $d(x,y)= \max \{|x|,|y|\}$ to be a metric on $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$ space
other properties are obvious but i don't know where to go with this
$$d(x,y) \le d(x,z) + d(z,y)$$
then
$$\max\{|x|,|y|\} \le \max\{|x|,|z|\} + \max\{|z|,|y|\}$$
then i'm stuck :)

Comment: Hint for simplifying things. Think of $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ as the complex numbers. Obviously the norm (meaning the absolute value) will not change. That should make it easier to see what is going on. Draw circles for the absolute values if that helps.

Comment: The function $d$ above is not a metric. $d(1,1) = 1$ but it should be zero to be a metric.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4810055/42969

Comment: Must be homework time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using cases, and sub cases.

Case 1. $\max\{|x|,|y|\} = |x|$.

Case 1.1. $\max\{|x|,|z|\} = |x|$. This sub case it's fulfilled since $|x| \leq |x| + r$ where $r$ is any positive number (i.e $\max\{|z|,|y|\}$).

Case 1.2. $\max\{|x|,|z|\} = |z|$. This sub case means that  $|x| \leq |z| = \max\{|x|,|z|\} \leq \max\{|x|,|z|\} + r$ where $r$ is any positive number.

Notices that this covers all cases for Case 1. since it did not mattered the value of $\max\{|z|,|y|\}$, the only thing important about this value is that is positive.

Case 2. $\max\{|x|,|y|\} = |y|$...

can you finish?

**Edit** copper.hat is right, that is not a metric, although you can still show the triangle inequality, the axiom of $d(x,x) = 0$ for all $x$ is not fulfilled.